# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Spring Boot 3.0.5 is in use.
I set ddl-auto as follows, but ddl-auto is set to create.

```
spring:
  security.debug: false
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

However, if you change the settings as follows, it will work fine.

```
spring:
  security.debug: false
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
```

The default value for ddl-auto is known as none, but we have confirmed that the value passed in the HibernateProperties.setDdlAuto method is "create".
The database is using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for the JPA property:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

or

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: false
```

Comment: If you add spring.jpa.generate-ddl: false, we will proceed with the drop table.